# Magento 2 server always full with cache files

Tags: magento2

Hi I am running my Magento 2.4.1 site in AWS with almost 3000 SKU but in a day it creates 40 50 GB of cache files I have correct permission website is running without any expectation error
how to control this cache problem
or how can I create Magento 2 Cron job to clear cache automatically 2 3 times I a day

Comment: Which cache is it that is filling up ? Is it the image cache?

Comment: i don't know what cache is this how to know ?

Comment: The image cache is stored in: pub/media/catalog/product/cache